# HEAP: Remove duplicate name and add there values in single entry

Tags: mysql

I am using HEAP with MYSQL database and I want to get the data so I am using below query.

```
select SUBSTRING (name, 1, CHARINDEX ('*' , name) - 1) as name, duration
FROM (
           SELECT b."identity" || '*' || session_id || '-' || a.user_id AS "name"
             ,MIN(time) AS "start"
             ,MAX(time) AS "last"
           ,((DATEDIFF('milliseconds', MIN(time), MAX(time))::FLOAT / 1000  ) / 60) AS "duration"

     FROM abc_app_production.all_events a ,abc_app_production.users b
     where    a.user_id = b.user_id
     AND b.user_type IS NOT NULL
     AND b."identity" IS NOT NULL
     AND b."identity" NOT IN ('Shubham')
     AND time >= convert(datetime,'2018-10-01') AND time <= convert(datetime,'2018-11-01')
   GROUP BY 1
     )
```

But I am getting duplicate name and duration as :

```
name            duration

John            0.27
John            0.5
Butler          0.0
Tom             29.64
Tom             10.00
Kathi Mike      0.0
Manish          4.38
```

But I want to add all duration in a single row which is repeating like :

```
name            duration

John            0.77
Butler          0.0
Tom             39.64
Kathi Mike      0.0
Manish          4.38
```

I tried a lot but getting errors. Please help and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need sum() aggregation and you are getting error becuase your group by clause was putting wrong place - it should be outside of subquery

```
select SUBSTRING (name, 1, CHARINDEX ('*' , name) - 1) as name, sum(duration) as duration
FROM (
           SELECT b."identity" || '*' || session_id || '-' || a.user_id AS "name"
             ,MIN(time) AS "start"
             ,MAX(time) AS "last"
           ,((DATEDIFF('milliseconds', MIN(time), MAX(time))::FLOAT / 1000  ) / 60) AS "duration"

     FROM abc_app_production.all_events a ,abc_app_production.users b
     where    a.user_id = b.user_id
     AND b.user_type IS NOT NULL
     AND b."identity" IS NOT NULL
     AND b."identity" NOT IN ('Shubham')
     AND time >= convert(datetime,'2018-10-01') AND time <= convert(datetime,'2018-11-01') 
     group by b."identity" || '*' || session_id || '-' || a.user_id
)X group by SUBSTRING (name, 1, CHARINDEX ('*' , name) - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks @fa06
Still getting error: Invalid operation: column "b.identity" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;